# return records in sql server which has data in a particular format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a SQL database table column which has data in this format "0000-00-0000"

for ex: "1234-98-2010"

For it has data in other formats as well.

I need to pick out all the records where the format is "0000-00-0000" irrespective of the data. Its the format  which i am after

Please, can some one advise me on how i can pick these records in sql server 2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT '1234-98-2010' AS S UNION ALL SELECT 'foo'
)
SELECT S 
FROM T 
WHERE S LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: +1. This will ensure the data has numbers only, whereas my solution left it open for any character.

Comment: lovely that worked like a dream. Wish i could do +10 for this. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the [like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator with a pattern

```
Select * from TableA
Where ColumnA like '[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]-[0123456789][0123456789]-[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn LIKE '____-__-____'
```

The `_` is a wildcard for one character.

Comment: This would include letters and numbers.  and I know the question doesn't specifically say..but I believe he only wants numbers between dashes.  "1234-56-7890' not 'abcd-ef-ghij'

Comment: @John: indeed; I commented the same on Martin's answer. Thanks for your insight. OP asked for **where the format is "0000-00-0000" irrespective of the data**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
WHERE c1 LIKE '____-__-____'
```